# Combinations of unique products with itertools

Tags: python, list, permutation, python-itertools

I have a nested list and would like to make a product of two items.

```
test = [[('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR')], 
        [('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR')],
        [('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN')]]
```

What I expect is something like this:

```
[(('juice', 'NOUN'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR')), 
 (('juice', 'NOUN'), ('chip', 'NOUN')),
 (('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR')),
 (('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN')),
 (('lemon', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN'))]
```

That is to say, I would like to get the permutation across lists but only for unique items. I prefer to use `itertools`. Previously, I tried `list(itertools.product(*test))` But I realized it would produce the product of the length of a nested list...

My current code:

```
unique_list = list(set(itertools.chain(*test)))
list(itertools.combinations(unique_list, 2))
```

My thought process is to get the unique items in the nested list first, so the nested list will be  `[[('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR')], [('lemon', 'FLAVOR')], [('chip', 'NOUN')]]` and then use the `itertools.combinations` to permute. Yet, it will permute within the list (i.e. juice and orange appear together), which I do not want in my results.

Comment: why do you not have `(('lemon', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN'))` in your results?

Comment: @Ev. Kounis oh! Thanks for pointing out! I want that in my results. I just edited my question

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any code you could show?

Comment: is the length of the original list fixed?

Comment: I don't understand why `(('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR'))` isn't part of the expected output. It (and its reverse) can be made a whole bunch of ways from your three input lists.

Comment: @Blckknght I don't want to get the self-permuted result

Comment: You can make it from any two of the lists, you don't need to match one with itself. I'd think it would be allowed if `(('juice', 'NOUN'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR'))` is, since that's a subset of the middle list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want **without** fixing the size of the original list to 3:

Input:

```
test = [[('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR')], 
        [('juice', 'NOUN'), ('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR')],
        [('juice', 'NOUN'), ('chip', 'NOUN')]]
```

First, reformat input to remove duplicates (see note 1):

```
test = [[x for x in sublist if x not in sum(test[:i], [])] for i, sublist in enumerate(test)]
```

Finally, get the [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
from itertools import combinations, product

for c in combinations(test, 2):
    for x in product(*c):
        print(x)
```

which produces:

```
(('juice', 'NOUN'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR'))
(('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('lemon', 'FLAVOR'))
(('juice', 'NOUN'), ('chip', 'NOUN'))
(('orange', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN'))
(('lemon', 'FLAVOR'), ('chip', 'NOUN'))
```

---

1. removes inner tuples if they were seen in any of the previous sublists. The magic here is done by the `sum(test[:i], [])` which "adds" all the previous sublists together to perform one membership check only.

---

There is also a list-comprehension version of the above for compactness and style-points:

```
res = [x for c in combinations(test, 2) for x in product(*c)]
```

Comment: I tested all the solutions you suggested and they worked like magic! Thanks

Comment: @Abbey Cheers! it was an interesting problem.